# OnApplyTemplate doesn't capture the BindingContext of the parent?

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding

In a test project, I'm trying to get the `BindingContext` of the parent control with template binding,

here, in the `MainPage`, I have two templates `temp1` and `temp2`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyXam.ViewModels"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyXam.Views"
             x:Class="MyXam.Views.MainPage"
             x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="temp1">
                <views:View1/>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="temp2">
                <views:View2/>
            </ControlTemplate>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout x:Name="stk">
        <Button Text="Switch view" Command="{Binding SwitchViewCommand}"/>
        <ContentView x:Name="cv" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource temp2}" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <ContentView.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentView" Binding="{Binding IsView1}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource temp2}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentView" Binding="{Binding IsView1, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource temp1}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </ContentView.Triggers>
        </ContentView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I want to get the `BindingContext` of the `MainPage` in `View2`, in the ctor:

```
SetBinding(BindingContextProperty, new Binding("Parent.BindingContext", source: RelativeBindingSource.TemplatedParent));
```

but when I try to get its vzlue in the `OnApplyTemplate` it's null:

```
 protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
 {
     base.OnApplyTemplate();
     vm = this.GetValue(BindingContextProperty);
 }
```

However binding is resolved in xaml:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name, Source={Reference this}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see the detail of your other code, but you can refer to the following code.

Define a `BindableProperty`  for this Label in `xaml.cs` and use the Name Property,e.g. `x:Name="TestControlView"` and binding like this

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestControlView}, Path=TestText}" />
```

You can check the full demo [here](https://github.com/jessiezh0320/CustomeViewDemo). 
The main code is like this:

TestControl.xaml.cs(TestControl is a ContentView)

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class TestControl : ContentView
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty TestTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TestText), typeof(string), typeof(TestControl));
    public string TestText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        
}
```

TestControl.xaml

MainPage.xaml

```
 <ListView  x:Name="lstView" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HasUnevenRows="True"  RefreshAllowed="true" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="0,5,0,5">
                              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                            <controls:TestControl TestText="{Binding Title}"  VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Type}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="#F0BB7F" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                              </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
 {
    public ObservableCollection<TestModel> veggies { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        veggies = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>();

        veggies.Add(new TestModel { Title = "Tomato", Type = "Fruit" });
        veggies.Add(new TestModel { Title = "Zucchini", Type = "Vegetable" });
        veggies.Add(new TestModel { Title = "Tomato" , Type = "Vegetable" });
        veggies.Add(new TestModel { Title = "Romaine", Type = "Fruit" });
        veggies.Add(new TestModel { Title = "Zucchini", Type = "Vegetable" });

        lstView.ItemsSource = veggies;

        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```